Method of images for a sphere
I know that for a circle, the process for modifying Green's function to account for the boundary condition $u(a,\theta) = 0$ is to (from geometric arguments) create an image at the point $\textbf{x}_0*$ (where $\textbf{x}_0 = \gamma \textbf{x}_0*$). Here is a reference image to help illustrate:

Where instead of a generic source $\textbf{x}_0$, we have a point charge $q$ with a position vector $\textbf{p}$ and a reflected point charge $-q$ with a position vector $\textbf{p}* =\gamma \textbf{p}$ where I'll assume it was determined that $\gamma = \frac{R^2}{p^2}$. And what we desire is to create a relationship between $\textbf{r}_1$ and $\textbf{r}_2$ using the Law of Cosines and the fact that they both share the same angle, $\phi$. These vectors will be defined as: $\textbf{r}_1=\textbf{r}-\textbf{p}$, and $\textbf{r}_2=\textbf{r}-\textbf{p}*$.
Green's function becomes the combination of Green's function for the source term at $\textbf{x}_0$ and another for the image source term at $\textbf{x}_0*$: $G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\ln\Big(\frac{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0|^2}{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0*|^2}\Big)+c$, where we want this Green's function to satisfy the Dirichlet boundary condition $u(a,\theta) = 0$:
$$G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0) = 0 \ \ \ \ \text{where } |\textbf{x}| = a$$
or to match the illustration: $G(\textbf{r},\textbf{p}) = 0$ where $|\textbf{r}| = a$. We start by creating a relationship between the distance between the location of the source at $\textbf{x}_0$ at the boundary condition where $|\textbf{x}| = r = a$ and where the source is felt at $\textbf{x}$, and between the image source at $\textbf{x}_0$ and where the image source is felt at $\textbf{x}$:
$$|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0|^2=k|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0*|^2 : |\textbf{x}| = r = a$$
. From the law of cosines, we can determine these distance $|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0|^2 = (\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0)\cdot(\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0) = |\textbf{x}|^2+|\textbf{x}_0|^2-2|\textbf{x}||\textbf{x}|_0\cos(\theta)$, where when the location of where the source is felt is at $a = |\textbf{x}|$ the boundary condition arises, and also realizing that the magnitude of the position vector of the source is $r_0$ i.e. we can substitute $|\textbf{x}_0| = r_0$,
$\tag{1}a^2+r_0^2-2ar_0\cos(\theta) = k\Big(a^2+\gamma^2r_0^2-2\gamma rr_0\cos(\theta)\Big)$.
Where we recognize that from the illustration that the angles, $\theta$, between $\textbf{r}_1 = \textbf{r}-\textbf{p}$, and $\textbf{r}_2 = \textbf{r}-\textbf{p}*$ are the same.
and we also want the following relationship to be true as well to create a relationship between our new coefficient, $k$, and the original coefficient we wanted to find, $\gamma$:
$\tag{2}2ar_0 \cos(\theta) = 2k\gamma ar_0\cos(\theta)$,
then $k = \frac{1}{\gamma}$, and using this result in (1) we can then arrive to $\gamma = \frac{a^2}{r_0^2}$. From these 2 coefficients, we can now look to fully evaluating our Green's function which satisfies the Dirichlet boundary condition. On the boundary condition where $|\textbf{x}| = a$, $G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0) = 0 = \frac{1}{4\pi}\ln\Big(\frac{a^2-r_0^2-2ar\cos(\theta)}{a^2+r_0*^2-2ar_0\cos(\theta)}\Big)+c \rightarrow c = -\frac{1}{4\pi}\ln(k)$, so $G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\Big(\frac{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0|^2}{|\textbf{x}-\textbf{x}_0*|^2 k}\Big)$, and after the identified coefficients, our Green's function which satisfies the boundary condition at $r = a$ is now:
$$G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}_0) = \frac{1}{4\pi} \ln\Big(\frac{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|^2}{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0*|^2}\frac{a^2}{\textbf{r}_0^2}\Big) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\ln\Big(a^2\frac{r^2+r_0^2-2rr_0\cos(\theta)}{r^2r_0^2+a^4-2rr_0a^2\cos(\theta)}\Big)$$
And at $|\textbf{x}| = r = a$, $G(\textbf{x},\textbf{x}_0) = 0$.

Now I'd like to create an analog for a sphere so that I can take into account the boundary conditions for a spherical volume, I need to know how to obtain the modified infinite space Green's function for a sphere instead. My textbook does not cover this, so some guidance would be appreciated.
$$\Delta u(r,\theta,\phi) = Q(r,\theta,\phi) \ \ \ \ 0\le r < \infty \land 0\le \theta \le \pi , 0 \le \phi \le 2\pi \\ \cases{u(r,\theta,0) = u(r,\theta,2\pi)\\ u'(r,\theta,0) = u'(r,\theta,2\pi) \\ u(a,\theta,\phi) = u(\theta,\phi)}$$
I drew a position vector pointing to a point $(r,\theta,\phi)$ where the source is felt some distance away from the source, $\textbf{r}$, and a position vector pointing to the point $(r_0,\theta_0,\phi_0)$ where the source is located. So we have two different positions with different radii, azimuth, and inclination. After drawing it all out, I came to find that for a position vector pointing to a source image at the point $(r_0*,\theta_0*,\phi_0*)$, $\textbf{r}_0*$ which is parallel to $\textbf{p} = \textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0$, that both $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the same between $\textbf{p}$ and $\textbf{p}* = \textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0*$, just like the angles between $\textbf{r}$ and $\textbf{p}$ and $\textbf{r}$ and $\textbf{p}*$ were the same.
Assuming the relationship $\textbf{r} = \gamma \textbf{r}_0*$ is true, then what I'd need to know next is how to formulate the distances:
$$|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0| = k|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0*|$$
Just like earlier, we can take advantage of the dot product to create a formula for the magnitudes of these now 3D vectors where $\theta$ is now the 3D angle between the vectors and is the same between the vectors $\textbf{r}$ and $\textbf{r}_0$, and $\textbf{r}$ and $\textbf{r}_0*$.
$$(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0)\cdot (\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0) = |\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|^2 = \textbf{r}^2 + \textbf{r}_0^2 - 2\textbf{r}\textbf{r}_0\cos(\theta) \\ 
(\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0*)\cdot (\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0*) = |\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0*|^2 = \textbf{r}^2 + \textbf{r}_0*^2 - 2\textbf{r}\textbf{r}_0*\cos(\theta)$$
So with the boundary condition being at $|\textbf{r}| = r =  a$ and $|\textbf{r}_0| = r_0$ we would gain a similar relationship as we did for the 2D case:
$$\tag{1}\sqrt{a^2 + r_0^2 - 2ar_0\cos(\theta)} = k\sqrt{a^2 + \gamma^2 r_0^2 - 2\gamma a r_0\cos(\theta)}$$
And I'm presuming we force the same relationship as well:
$$\tag{2} \sqrt{-2ar_0\cos(\theta)}= k\sqrt{- 2\gamma a r_0\cos(\theta)}$$
so that $k = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma}}$. Now (1) becomes: $\sqrt{a^2 + r_0^2 - 2ar_0\cos(\theta)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\gamma}}\sqrt{a^2 + \gamma^2 r_0^2 - 2\gamma a r_0\cos(\theta)}$ so our equation becomes $a^2 + r_0^2 - 2ar_0\cos(\theta) = \frac{a^2}{\gamma} + \gamma r_0^2 - 2ar_0\cos(\theta)$ and we can cancel out the cosine terms now to get
$$\tag{3} a^2 + r_0^2 = \frac{a^2}{\gamma} + \gamma r_0^2 \rightarrow \gamma = \frac{a^2}{r_0^2}$$ which is the exact same relationship obtained in the 2D case for a circular boundary.
We will now look at evaluating $c$ now that we have our relationships for $|\textbf{r}| = r = a$,
$$G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}_0):(r=a) = G(\theta,\phi) = \frac{1}{4\pi}\Big(\frac{|\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0| - |\textbf{r}-\gamma\textbf{r}_0|}{|\textbf{r}-\gamma\textbf{r}_0||\textbf{r}-\textbf{r}_0|}\Big):(r=a) + c \\
= \frac{1}{4\pi}\Big(\frac{k|\textbf{r}-\gamma\textbf{r}_0| - |\textbf{r}-\gamma\textbf{r}_0|}{k|\textbf{r}-\gamma\textbf{r}_0|^2}\Big):(r=a) + c \\ 
= \frac{1}{4\pi}\Big(\frac{(k-1)}{k|\textbf{r}-\gamma\textbf{r}_0|:(r=a)}\Big) + c$$
$$c = G(\theta,\phi) + \frac{1}{4\pi}\Big(\frac{(1-k)}{k|\textbf{r}-\gamma\textbf{r}_0|:(r=a)}\Big)$$
With this, our Green's function becomes:
$$\tag{4}G(\textbf{r},\textbf{r}_0) = G(\theta,\phi) + \frac{\Big(\sqrt{r^2+r_0^2-2ar_0\cos\theta}-\sqrt{r^2+\frac{a^4}{r_0^2}-2a^3r_0\cos\theta}\Big)\sqrt{a^2+r_0^2-2ra\cos\theta}}{\sqrt{r^2+r_0^2-2ar_0\cos\theta}\sqrt{r^2+\frac{a^4}{r_0^2}-2a^3r_0\cos\theta}\sqrt{a^2+r_0^2-2ra\cos\theta}} \\
= G(\theta,\phi) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+\frac{a^4}{r_0^2}-2a^3r_0\cos\theta}} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{r^2+r_0^2-2ar_0\cos\theta}}$$
Is this correct?
